# Problem creating virtual device after installed Android Studio 3.4 + Intel HAXM 7.5.2

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

After installed, I receive a message like this:

```
Recommendation:
Recommentation /dev/kvm not found. Troubleshoot
```

and

```
Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module.
```

Any solution to solve this?

Comment: @cccnrc There should be no code. Maybe you should be the one rereading the question.

Answer (score 0):

For linux:

> On older computers: F1 or the key combination CTRL+ALT+ESC. Turn ON
>   the System. Press F2 key at startup BIOS Setup. Press the right arrow
>   key to System Configuration tab, Select Virtualization Technology and
>   then press the Enterkey. Select Enabled and press the Enter key.

(Source: https://2nwiki.2n.cz/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75202968)

Comment: Is on WIndows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable virtualization technology in your computer's bios, do a Google search on instructions as per machine you are using.

Virtualization will then come into immediate effect.

Comment: The "virtualization technology" was enabled in BIOS.